# Split string into array based on characters, in a loop

Tags: python, string

I would like to only extract the following characters from the following strings:

```
numbers = '0123456789'
operators = '^/*+-%dr='
```

from a given string, into a list, without using regex or any imported modules.

I would like the numbers to remain contiguous, but the operators to have a space in between them in the final list.

For example:

Input :  `'3096+41*12-dd+31^2rrr'`

Output : `[3096,+,41,*,12,-,d,d,+,31,2,r,r,r]`

How can I do this as efficiently as possible?

Comment: Why not just loop through each character and build a new array manually when you encounter one of the operators?

Comment: @JBallin I need to reserve the order, i.e which operator applies to which number

Answer (score 0):

```
digits = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
operators = ['+', '-'....]
number = ''
output = []

for char in input:
    if char in digits:
        number += char
    elif char in operators:
        output.append(number)
        output.append(char)
        number = ''

output.append(number)
```

Comment: Something like this should work, bear in mind the output list will contain strings still so if you require the numbers in integer form they must be parsed.

Comment: Also bear in mind it will ignore characters that don't match

Comment: `list` objects do not have an `.includes()` method, nor do they have a `.push()`. Membership checks are done by the `in` operator. Also, use a `set` instead of a `list` if you're using it for membership checks. Also, no `else if` and `end` in Python. The question is tagged python.

Comment: My bad saw the wrong tag for another question I will edit for python

Answer (score 0):

String-based following the task (even as packages/regex are preferred due to speed and elegance). We only distinguish integers >= 1 digit and given operators:

```
numbers = '0123456789'
operators = '^/*+-%dr='

inp = '3096+41*12-dd+31^2rrr'

outp = []
cn = '' # current number 
for i in range(len(inp)):
    if inp[i] in numbers: # check string element-wise
        cn += inp[i] # compile current number
    elif inp[i] in operators:
        if len(cn) > 0: # we have an integer in store (as string)
            outp.append(int(cn)) # which we append as int
            cn = '' # and clear for the next number
        outp.append(inp[i])
    else:
        pass # todo: non-treatable tokens

print(outp)
```

output:

```
[3096, '+', 41, '*', 12, '-', 'd', 'd', '+', 31, '^', 2, 'r', 'r', 'r']
```

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_